# Java Applet on ftp server taking several minutes to connect to a MySQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, database, ftp, applet

First of all, this is a **self signed applet** so the permissions is okay.
Secondly, the applet is uploaded to an ftp server and is opened with an .html document.

The code itself I use to connect is this:

```
try
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://the.hostname:3306/qnqdb", "username", "password");
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, (end - start) + "ms.\n" + conn);
}
catch (SQLException ex)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, ex.getClass() + "\n" + ex.getMessage());
}
```

The JOptionPane shows it took 127 seconds (Just over 4,5 minutes), no matter what DB I connect to, it still takes forever the first time.

**If I connect to it again, it only takes from 200-2000ms** (Seems normal)

To test it, I also opened op Wireshark and listend to port 3306. The first 4 minutes nothing happened at all. [Image of the capture](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/99717/Wireshark.png)
Then during the next 50 seconds it recorded 28 packets.

The strange thing is, if I connect to the DB while running the applet locally, it only takes ~500ms the first time and ~200ms afterwards.

What I'm thinking is:

- It's not the database fault, since it's quick to connect the 2nd to n'th time.
- The applet is somehow at fault. Maybe class loading takes a long time for some reason.

If it has any importance, then a normal socket connection from the applet only takes 20-30ms both locally and on the ftp.

**Edit**
Apparently, on other computers, it doesn't take quite so long. On one I tried it was ~20 seconds, while on another it's supposedly only 2-3 sec.
**Update:** It does indeed seem like it's only this one computer it takes ages.
The log of Java Console level 5: http://pastebin.com/2u2v7gZV

Comment: What output do you see in the [Java Console])(http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml)?  Make sure the trace level is set to 5.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Here you go: http://pastebin.com/2u2v7gZV When I connected a 2nd time. It **only** said "Connecting http://prod0.magentohotel.dk:3306/ with proxy=DIRECT" which it only said once in the first time (Line 886)

Comment: quick question (I have not gone over the trace yet) - any reason why the DB logic had to be in the applet and not in a service to which the applet could communicate with?

Comment: also, are you using a proxy server for connectivity?  can you test the case where no proxy is involved to check if that could be causing any issues - also, are you using ipv6 or 4?

Comment: @Alihaider I have read a lot about using a servelet to or alike to communicate with the database, I am just not sure if the service hoster I'm using supports that. And no, there's no proxy and ipv4 at all tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the Java console log one more time, I noticed one thing.

I kept repeating

```
network: Connecting http://shop.nordicbeads.com/Renes/mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar with 
proxy=DIRECT network: Cache entry not found [url: http://shop.nordicbeads.com/Renes/mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar, version: null]
```

Over and over again, but then I noticed the path it uses is for some reason not the path to the library on the ftp server. The path is Renes/lib/library.jar and it didn't use look in the lib folder.
I changed the position of the library and it connects in just 3 seconds now.

The strange thing is, why does all other computers I tested this on look in the lib folder right away. And why does mine take over 4 minutes to look there?
In the html document I even added the library in the archive line with lib/ in front, but having that or not doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  :)  Thanks for reporting the solution.  As to the 'why', maybe  1.7.0_05-b05 is a little buggy.